Modem RC7611 cannot connect in the ATT carrier
I have a problem with the GPRS modem RC7611 of Sierra Wireless, it initialize correctly, finding the sim card and respond the AT commands, but when it will connect in the carrier, it receive a denied status:
AT+CGMM

RC7611

OK

AT+KCELL=0

37,8,4,6,5035,184,36,9

OK

AT+CREG=0

OK

AT+CMEE=1

OK

AT+KPATTERN="EOF"

OK

AT+KURCCFG="TCP",1,0

OK

AT+CTZU=1

OK

AT+CLCK="SC",2

OK

AT+CPIN?

OK

AT+CCID

+CLCK: 0

OK

AT+CCID

+CPIN: READY

OK

AT+CCID

+CCID: 89011703278703002751

OK

AT+COPS=0,2

OK

AT+CREG?

+CREG: 0,3

OK

AT+CREG?

+CREG: 0,3

OK

I have already verified the firmware version, the carrier preference and both are alright:
AT+CGMR

SWI9X07H_00.09.10.00 85890e jenkins 2023/09/25 03:16:56

OK

AT!IMAGE?

TYPE SLOT STATUS LRU FAILURES UNIQUE_ID   BUILD_ID
FW   1    EMPTY  0   0 0                  
FW   2    EMPTY  0   0 0                  
FW   3    EMPTY  0   0 0                  
Max FW images: 1
Active FW image is at slot 255

TYPE SLOT STATUS LRU FAILURES UNIQUE_ID  BUILD_ID
PRI  FF   GOOD   0   00      001.096_000 00.09.10.00_ATT
PRI  FF   GOOD   0   00      001.094_000 00.08.20.00_GENERIC
PRI  FF   GOOD   0   00      001.050_000 00.08.20.00_TMO
PRI  FF   GOOD   0   00      001.066_000 00.08.20.00_VERIZON
Max PRI images: 50

OK

AT!IMPREF?

!IMPREF: 
 preferred fw version:    00.09.10.00
 preferred carrier name:  ATT
 preferred config name:   ATT_001.096_000
 preferred subpri index:  001
 current fw version:      00.09.10.00
 current carrier name:    ATT
 current config name:     ATT_001.096_000
 current subpri index:    001

OK

Someone can help me with this issue ?
